# Javascript ES6 template strings function names - Chrome OK, Firefox KO - Seems like a transpilation issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, ecmascript-6, template-strings

How to call dynamic function names across browsers ?
I have seen some ways to do it but none as "elegant" as below.
Issue is it is working in Chrome, but not in Firefox and not in Safari.

If I call

```
const component = "a";
this[component]() // console: Called a
this[`${component}`]() // console: Called a
```

On Chrome it works fine, the function is called correctly.
On Firefox it says

```
TypeError: this[("" + component)] is not a function
```

How should I do if I want to achieve this ?

**EDIT** to add more context

Framework is React.

Example:

```
    export default class MyComp extends Component {

    a() {
        console.log("Called a");
    }
    b() {
        console.log("Called b");
    }
    c() {
        console.log("Called c");
    }

    renderAThing(component) {
        return this[component]();
    }

    render() {
        return this.renderAThing("a");
    }
}
```

If I call directly thiscomponent in the render() it works.

**EDIT 2** It seems that this is a transpilation issue and not a browser issue. As you pointed out, the code is valid for Chrome and Firefox.
I am using React alongside Meteor and Babel.
Thanks @Jaromanda X for the hint.

FYI, the minified (=production) Meteor code is also not working on Chrome.

Comment: Please add a complete code example.

Comment: I tried in Safari and it worked. Perhaps using "window" instead of "this"?

Comment: It does work in Firefox 58 and 59.

Comment: Assuming you mean `function a(){`…`}` instead of `a(){`…`}`, this works in Firefox. Of course, relying on `this` being the global scope in strict mode, fails, but even then, the error message is not reproducible.

Comment: `Example` is clearly not complete ... you can't just define functions like that

Comment: Are those methods part of a `class`? Please only post syntactically correct and complete snippets

Comment: why would the error say `this[("" + component)] is not a function` - since  your code does not contain such a construct - if `a` were indeed not a function, firefox would produce the following error `this[(intermediate value)] is not a function` - therefore, I suggest the code you posted is not the code you are using in firefox

Comment: @str I have added a more complete example

Comment: @Bergi yes indeed

Comment: @JaromandaX edited with more code

Comment: @JaromandaX Right the error is not the same if I call this[component]() or this[`${component}`](). The error in the message is by calling the second option

Comment: `this[\`${component}\`]` **is** the second option ... so, I don't understand the above comment at all

Comment: So, this is the code you write ... but what does the code look like **in the browser** - it seems you're transpiling

Comment: what is `this.props` ...

Comment: @JaromandaX that's a good point. It is transpiled to var componentValue = this["" + component]();

Comment: this.props are component properties, this is a React thing. I am going to edit this to be more generic

Comment: can you add a runnable snippet that demonstrates the problem, i.e. it works in chrome but not in firefox

Comment: @JaromandaX I think you are right, this is a transpilation issue. As the minified (=production) code also threw an error in Chrome. I changed the way I handled it, update coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is not a browser issue but a transpilation one, I ended up handling it in a totally different way. It goes like this :

```
export default class DateTimePicker extends Component {
getComponentValue(component) {
    const { value } = this.props; // React properties

    if (!value) return null;
    if (component === "a") return value.getA();
    if (component === "b") return value.getB();
    return null;
}

renderA(component) {
    const componentValue = this.getComponentValue(component);

    return (
        <div>{componentValue}</div>
    );
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderA("a")}
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

I am not really satisfied but I guess it's OK for now.

Answer (score 0):

This code works on Firefox 58 :

```
function a() {
  console.log("Called a");
}

function b() {
  console.log("Called b");
}

function c() {
  console.log("Called c");
}

const component = "a";
this[component]() // console: Called a
this[`${component}`]() // console: Called a
```

But i suppose your problem is the `this` keyword. You can replace it by `window` to avoid it. But it all depends where your code is.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question to give more context

Answer (score 0):

Shorthand method definition can be used in a method declaration on object literals and ES6 classes.

**For example:**

```
class myClass {
    a() {
        console.log("Called a");
    }
    b() {
        console.log("Called b");
    }
    c() {
        console.log("Called c");
    }
}
```

**Or within Object:**

```
var myObject = {  
  a() {...},
  b() {...}
  .
  .
}
```

In your case, you need to create your functions either as [Declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) or [Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function):

```js
function a() {
  console.log("Called a");
}
function b() {
  console.log("Called b");
}
function c() {
  console.log("Called c");
}

const component = "a";
this[component]() // console: Called a
this[`${component}`]() // console: Called a
```

Comment: No, if you want to access them by name as a property, they should *not* be plain function declarations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how would you proceed with my edited example ?

Comment: @Franck how you're setting this attr `this.props`?

Comment: @Ele I posted my own answer, I think it is a transpilation issue